# Should I use an Intermediate node on my Neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am new to graph databases, and I am trying to make an application where users can post text and have it relate to other text. For instance, a user Sarah might want to link the node containing the text 'I should pay my taxes' with a relationship type 'supportedBy' pointing to the text 'The IRS will hunt me down, and I will go to jail if I don't'. However, I want to link the relationship to the person who originally forged it. I can think of a couple ways to do it, but I don't know the way that will result in best performance and data storage. All the ways I can think to do it end up repeating information, and I don't want the database to be bloated.

Primary way is to introduce an intermediate node that Sarah points to with relationship 'made'. Other users could in turn could 'claim' the node to essentially upvote the intermediate node and stop it from being deleted if the original maker chooses to sever the connection. This intermediate node then point to the two original nodes with 'supportedBy' and 'supporting'.

Am I thinking about this right, or is there a better way to approach this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a couple of attribute fields to annotate the SupportedBy edge between claims. One could be "Original Claim" with value Sarah, with other attributes "Upvotes" and "Downvotes" that get usernames appended as a vector/list. A simple query on the length of the Upvote and Downvote attributes yields your net score.